# How to get the three highest values from all the arrays using only the <stdio.h> library

Tags: c

Hey Guys i managed to complete finding the Three highest for the whole array table. Is my method correct?

```
int Man[] = { 18080,18961,18985,18761,17821,19021,18452,20000 };
int Infra[] = { 4922,4904,4993,5076,4970,4900,4718,4757 };
int Ser[] = { 13898,14424,14290,14362,12623,13139,13775,15081 };
int Trans[] = { 7382,7323,7304,7675,7147,7335,6972,7740 };
int Others[] = { 1398,1438,1414,1435,1361,1420,1450,1476 };

void main(void)
{
int first = 0;
int second = 0;
int third = 0;
int i, k ;
//Find highest
for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    if (Q1_2015[i] > first)
        first = Q1_2015[i];
    if (Q2_2015[i] > first)
        first = Q2_2015[i];
    if (Q3_2015[i] > first)
        first = Q3_2015[i];
    if (Q4_2015[i] > first)
        first = Q4_2015[i];
    if (Q1_2016[i] > first)
        first = Q1_2016[i];
    if (Q2_2016[i] > first)
        first = Q2_2016[i];
    if (Q3_2016[i] > first)
        first = Q3_2016[i];
    if (Q4_2016[i] > first)
        first = Q4_2016[i];
}

//Find Second highest
for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    if (Q1_2015[i] < first && Q1_2015[i] > second)
        second = Q1_2015[i];
    if (Q2_2015[i] < first && Q2_2015[i] > second)
        second = Q2_2015[i];
    if (Q3_2015[i] < first && Q3_2015[i] > second)
        second = Q3_2015[i];
    if (Q4_2015[i] < first && Q4_2015[i] > second)
        second = Q4_2015[i];
    if (Q1_2016[i] < first && Q1_2016[i] > second)
        second = Q1_2016[i];
    if (Q2_2016[i] < first && Q2_2016[i] > second)
        second = Q2_2016[i];
    if (Q3_2016[i] < first && Q3_2016[i] > second)
        second = Q3_2016[i];
    if (Q4_2016[i] < first && Q4_2016[i] > second)
        second = Q4_2016[i];
}

//Find Third highest
for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    if (Q1_2015[i] < first && Q1_2015[i] < second && Q1_2015[i]>third)
        third = Q1_2015[i];
    if (Q2_2015[i] < first && Q2_2015[i] < second && Q2_2015[i]>third)
        third = Q2_2015[i];
    if (Q3_2015[i] < first && Q3_2015[i] < second && Q3_2015[i]>third)
        third = Q3_2015[i];
    if (Q4_2015[i] < first && Q4_2015[i] < second && Q4_2015[i]>third)
        third = Q4_2015[i];
    if (Q1_2016[i] < first && Q1_2016[i] < second && Q1_2016[i]>third)
        third = Q1_2016[i];
    if (Q2_2016[i] < first && Q2_2016[i] < second && Q2_2016[i]>third)
        third = Q2_2016[i];
    if (Q3_2016[i] < first && Q3_2016[i] < second && Q3_2016[i]>third)
        third = Q3_2016[i];
    if (Q4_2016[i] < first && Q4_2016[i] < second && Q4_2016[i]>third)
        third = Q4_2016[i];

}
```

I changed my data from row to column so it would easier for me to execute the coding for this task by the way whats with the website saying that i need more words in order to edit this post cause i have too many coding?

Comment: We are not your programmers, show some effort.

Comment: There is nothing in stdio.h which can help you for this. What you can do is sort each array and then it's trivial to get the 3 highest values. There is a standard sort algorithm, but you're out of luck because it's in stdlib.h and not in stdio.h. There are other ways too. How would _you_ do it by hand with with a pencil and a piece of paper?

Comment: Sorry, What i meant was is there a way to get the 3 highest data of all the array without using 2D array. Just need some clarification

Comment: @PicaLow yes there is a way, conactenate all arrays in a single temporary array and then apply what I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I was thinking of 2D array but it failed so now, get the highest for each column because most of the highest numbers are in int Man[] than after getting all the highest for all column, put it into an array and sort out it again. Is it possible?

Comment: Do what I told you in my previous comment and consider the last sentence in my first comment. Forget the idea of a 2D array, it's useless. Consider to [edit] your question and show what result exactly you expect. Is it the 3 highest values of every array, or is it the 3 highest values of all arrays together?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Mine is the 3 highest values of all arrays together. If i would to use stdlib.h which function should i look into?

Comment: @PicaLow `qsort` for sorting.

Answer (score 2):

The 3 highest values from all 40?

This shouldn't be too difficult

- Create 3 int variables to hold the required values and set them to 0 say a,b and c
- Loop through all 5 arrays checking if the current value is greater than a and if it is replace the value of a, when you are finished that a = the largest value.
- Loop through all 5 arrays again only this time with b and ignoring a (Or any value greater than or equal to a)
- Repeat that step with c ignoring any value greater than or equal to b)

It's frowned on here to ask people to do homework and you will get downvoted for it, but if you want to try that out and put your code up and I'll have a look for you.

Comment: OMG thanks. That clarified some of my doubts of the given question.

Comment: You are right, though I was basing it on the numbers above, it might be that the OP was looking for the 3 highest values in each array as the 3 highest are all in the int Man[] array

Comment: Loop through all 5 arrays again only this time with b and ignoring a (Or any value greater than or equal to a) How do you ignore the a in a if statement? I did this if (a <Q1_2015[i] > b). Is it correct?

Comment: It's another condition so the simplest way to explain it is an if inside an if

Comment: There's 8 elements in each array not 5 that code will not work at all, and the array's do not have the names you've used in your loops.